# Maintain session across multiple get requests in rspec request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, session-variables, rspec-rails

How do I ask rspec to use/keep-alive the session used for a previous request, for the next request.

If I print the session after the first get, it is different from the session I see in the action handling blah2_path.

```
get blah_path, {}, headers
get blah2_path, {}, headers # use same session as blah2_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this:

```
before :all do
  @my_session = ActionController::TestSession.new
end
before do
  controller.stub session: @my_session
end
```

Comment: btw this is not a controller spec, its a request spec